# Best Android BetaTesting

Tags: android

so, here it is my question.

Until now, we were using TestFlight for Beta Testing on Android, the problem is that not a long time ago, Apple bought it, so now it is going to be closed for the Android platform.

Anybody knows what's the best Beta-Testing platform for Android developing?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at the Google Play [Beta-testing and staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en). You can upload a new beta APK using the developer console, just like you would with a production version. However, your app will not be visible publicly on the Play Store (unless you also have a production APK).

You need to create a Google+ community or Google Group and have any testers become a member of this. Then, the app will become visible to them in the Play Store.

Comment: For future reference, you *can* actually view your app's PlayStore page if it is in alpha/beta, and you have the app installed. You can go to Play Store -> My apps -> click on your app. This is only really useful if you want to test how your page appears while still in dev.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that my answer didn't seem to acknowledge this, so I reworded it to hopefully be more explanatory. What I meant was that the app will not be visible on the Play Store to a user who is not in your testing group/community.

Comment: Understood - only pointed it out because that information can be helpful to those who want to see their page.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Google Play Developer Console [Advanced delivery options, Alpha and beta testing, staged rollouts](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about/distribution.html#advanced). See more details [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I heard about it, but, if there is a crash, are they sending the developer a detailed Log? Can I create custom Logs and to send it to the developer as well like on TestFlight or is it the same kind of Log as when I upload it on GooglePlay on production?

The point is that I would like a Beta-Testing platform with posibility to send custom logs to the developers and also all of the crashes the application has.

Thanks a lot!